# Cannot access GoDaddy subdomain link

Tags: google-chrome, dns

Our company has setup the GoDaddy sub-domain link for a while
But sometimes we find that some users are unable to access the link
and the error code is ERR_TIMED_OUT
So i check my PC if i got the same problem too.
I use my own profile for chrome, I cannot access the link either. But i can access it through incognito window.
I have no idea how to fix the current problem.
Is anyone can provide me the idea to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you checked w/ GoDaddy? Cleared cache? What does DNS say on the broken systems vs the working ones? Is the link just to the basic sub-domain.domain, or are there more parts to it? What sort of site is it running and have you checked the logs on the server side?

Comment: I have contacted GoDaddy to check it before. But seems like they refused to check it. They only keep saying they cannot access the link. The other subdomain link is working fine. For this subdomain link, the original link is accessible. It is an OneDrive Online link which requires to login accessible accounts.